# Google-Maps: Algorithm to find points not containing buildings in a given radius

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Given:

Area - area to be searched

Radius - radius without any buildings

the idea is to have an algorithm that uses google maps API to search for the points in a given area that doesn’t contain any buildings within a given radius.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0):

An interesting thought you should keep in mind, is that a named road will not increment the number if there is not a building.

For example let's say we have `named-road` and there are 4 buildings in the start of the road 1,2,3,4. In our example there are no buildings for 1km. The next building will have the number `5`. So that's a good way to start your algorithm.

You need to find all the roads within the selected radius, then search every road and check the distances between buildings.

I hope I helped a little.